# Returning row with zero instead of no result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which looks exactly like this:

```
SELECT aid, 
  COALESCE(SUM(s.amount),0) AS total_spend 
FROM rt_spends AS s 
WHERE `aid` = 7 
  AND `date` BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2013-12-09' 
GROUP BY s.aid
```

Which returns something along the lines of:

```
aid | total_spend
7       100.00
```

However in the event there are zero records in that daterange. I would like to output something such as

```
aid | total_spend
7       0.00
```

Would this be better suited for PHP or MySQL?

Comment: It will simply return zero results

Comment: Use a UNION SELECT, returning the 0 style result you like in the second SELECT and then a LIMIT 1 in an outer SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, and given that it's pretty complicated for a simple `SUM` query I think it also illustrates that you may be better off handling "no results" in PHP :)

```
SELECT aid, SUM(s.amount) AS total_spend
FROM (
  SELECT amount FROM rt_spends
    WHERE aid = 7 AND `date` BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2013-12-09'
  UNION SELECT 7, 0
) s
GROUP BY s.aid
```

Comment: I made a small change ans also added `aid` into the inner select but it worked like a charm. I will still look into handling no result with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Change COALESCE to IFNULL.

Coalesce is for comparisons, you're selecting.

Comment: This returns the same exact thing as my query

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating arkascha's comment:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  (SELECT aid, 
    COALESCE(SUM(s.amount),0) AS total_spend 
  FROM rt_spends AS s 
  WHERE `aid` = 7 
    AND `date` BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2013-12-09' 
  GROUP BY s.aid)

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT aid, 0 AS total_spend WHERE `aid` = '7')
) sub_query
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This returns a `1064` related too `syntax to use near 'WHERE `aid` = '7')
) sub_query
LIMIT 1' at line 12`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the from clause... `SELECT aid, 0 AS total_spend FROM rt_spends WHERE aid = '7'` ...

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone along the route of this but my memory for syntax is not the best:

```
SELECT aid, 
  COALESCE(sub.total_spent,0) AS total_spend 
FROM rt_spends AS s 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(rt_spends.amount) AS total_spent
        FROM rt_spends 
        WHERE `aid` = 7 
            AND `date` BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2013-12-09'
        GROUP BY rt_spends.aid
    ) AS sub
WHERE `aid` = 7 
GROUP BY s.aid
```

IMO though, you are probably better off doing this in the PHP as why get MySQL to do the work when there is nothing to get!?

You are passing the aid anyway so if 'total' is null do whatever you wanted to. The only reason I can think you would need to handle this in the query is if you are pulling more information out from the database and this is just one element of it i.e. you need the record to return other stuff even if there is no spend amounts but if there are amounts you need the total but just between the dates - which is why I would go down a subquery route.